Blazor WASM Deployment Not Including All wwwroot Folders and Files
I created a Blazor WASM application (.NET 9) and am deploying it to an Azure Static Web App. When running it locally, I have an xml file in a folder called 'resources' (under wwwroot) that it reads from when it loads and it works well. However, when deploying into an Azure Static Web App, the 'resources' folder doesn't deploy.
How do I get it to deploy the resources folder that contains the xml file?


I set the Build Action of the Xml file to 'Content' and set 'Copy to Output Directory' to both 'Copy if newer' and 'Copy always' but neither has worked.
I've tried moving the xml file to the scripts folder where it is properly deploying download.js but that doesn't work. I've redeployed this countless times into different Azure Static Web Apps and I'm at a loss as to what else to try.
Thanks in advance for any assistance.
I've also created other new blank WASM projects (with and without being a Progressive Web App) and deployed them as-is to Azure Static Web Apps and they all have the same issue as well of not deploying all additional wwwroot subfolders.

Try adding <Content Include="wwwroot\resources\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" /> in .csproj.

@PravallikaKV, in my .csproj file I have the following:


Always


Should I edit the Content Update or should I remove this and add the  in place of it?

Can you change it as I mentioned in the above comment and check once?

I will try from my end and update if it works.

@PravallikaKV, I'm getting the error: Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were: 'wwwroot\resources\MTD.xml' I'm not seeing the EnableDefaultContentItems so I can set it to false to see what happens. I replaced Content Update with the Content Include part.

Can you share your .csproj if possible?

Remove other ItemGroups related to wwwroot and add `
false



Always

`



net9.0
enable
enable
service-worker-assets.js












Always



Remove <Content Update="wwwroot\resources\T2unicMTD.mtdef"> and add only<Content Include="wwwroot\resources\**" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" /> instead. or remove all wwwroot related ItemGroup and add <Content Include="wwwroot\**">       <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>

Both ways I get duplicate content items included errors... you gave me an idea. With my original Content Update, I'm going to change it from CopyToOutputDirectory to CopyToPublishDirectory and see if that works.

Try using None instead of Content. <ItemGroup>     <None Include="wwwroot\**\*" />   </ItemGroup>

Are you able to see the xml file when you move the code to Git Hub.

when deploying into an Azure Static Web App, the 'resources' folder doesn't deploy.  Where you are checking the deployed files ?

I'm checking the folder structure in DevTools in the Sources tab. You can check yourself link to Azure Static Web App

I am able to see the folder with xml file when I try to access the file in URL.Image

@Harshitha I have noticed that if I type any random filename, it'll show that file (or folder) in the sources tab but the file doesn't actually exist.

yes..Even I observed the same

I did notice that the scripts/download.js doesn't appear unless I add  to one of my .razor files. When I do that with my xml file, it'll appear as well but it can't access it. I don't know if there's a different tag that I use if it's not a script so I'm trying different tags at this point so I can directly access the xml file (like how I can locally).

@BradB -  <link rel="xml" href="path/to/MDT.xml" type="application/xml"> try this and check once

That did not work. I also tried the  as well with differing variations of the type. In WASM, for the link tab, I'm not seeing a simple xml option, but tried every available option (including 'application/xml' & 'text/xml'). The only way I can get the file to show up is by  but I can't directly access it or reference it and the console complains that it's not a javascript file.

In the .razor file I had to add a script tag with type "text/template" and I moved the file to the 'scripts' folder as well.
<script src="scripts/MTD.xml" type="text/template"></script>

Interesting tidbit, for this to work the extension has to be .xml (albeit there may be other extensions that work but custom extensions I tried did not work).
